# How do I copy files to read only directory

Tags: 18.04, permissions, directory

I want to copy some files to a directory but it says permission denied. I already ran `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder` the last time which left my system in lots of problems that I had to re-install Ubuntu. How do I go about this please as I am quite new to using ubuntu.

Comment: What is the directory?

Comment: @Pilot6 the directory where i want to copy to is 'htdocs' while i am coping from an external drive

Comment: Where is 'htdocs' located? Please give a full path and I can give an example.

Comment: @Pilot6 The path to the htdocs directory from root: /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than copying the files with the `cp` command, i just granted permissions in the directory using `sudo chmod -R 777 htdocs`. Thanks all for the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to the files with 'sudo cp files directory' rather than to try to change the directory's permissions?
Or, if you're going to be copying multiple files one at a time, you can use 'sudo su' login as root, then you don't have to type the sudo each time.

Comment: i am aware of this already. But its a problem if i want to copy multiple files or directories at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy a directory located e.g. in your Home Directory to `/opt/lampp/htdocs` this way. Let the folder be `test`.

```
sudo cp ~/test /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

You can remove it by

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp/htdocs/test
```